# Firestore security rules for 2FA

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-identity

I'm building a serverless app with Firebase: Firestore and cloud functions. One thing I've been struggling with is how to validate that a user has 2FA enabled to allow access to certain functions.
Already enrolled into Google Identity Platform to allow 2FA, unfortunately I wasn't able to find an option to force 2FA.

My security rules requirements are: logged in, email verified, did authenticate with 2FA.

Current security rules in cloud firestore :

```
request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email_verified
```

As far as I've searched `request.auth.token.phone_number` can be checked, but that only checks if the user has registered a phone number, not if they have 2FA login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After taking this question to google groups for support, I found the answer:

```
if request.auth.token.firebase.get('sign_in_second_factor', null) == 'phone'
&& 'second_factor_identifier' in request.auth.token.firebase;
```

This will allow access if user has mobile phone as 2FA.

You can view the original by Sam on google groups: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/7EZfxETa_jk/m/4e0FRCpWAgAJ

Answer (score 0):

Google added Multi-factor authentication support to [Google Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa) projects back in [March](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_7110_-_march_12_2020) last year. As an example, to authenticate a user, you can structure your code to include the following steps:

1. Re-authenticate, the user;
2. Ask the user to enter their phone number;
3. Initialise: the reCAPTCHA verifier;
4. Get a multi-factor session for the user;
5. Initialise: a PhoneInfoOptions object with the user's phone number and the multi-factor session;
6. Send a verification message to the user's phone;
7. If the request fails, reset the reCAPTCHA;
8. Ask the user to verify the SMS code;
9. Initialise: a MultiFactorAssertion object;
10. Complete the enrollment;

You can find the code snippet below on the Firebase [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa#enrolling_a_second_factor) page if you are interested in reading more.

```
var recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(container);
user.multiFactor.getSession().then(function(multiFactorSession) {
  // Specify the phone number and pass the MFA session.
  var phoneInfoOptions = {
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    session: multiFactorSession
  };
  var phoneAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
  // Send SMS verification code.
  return phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneInfoOptions, recaptchaVerifier);
})
.then(function(verificationId) {
  // Ask user for the verification code.
  var cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, verificationCode);
  var multiFactorAssertion = firebase.auth.PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(cred);
  // Complete enrollment.
  return user.multiFactor.enroll(multiFactorAssertion, mfaDisplayName);
});
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, those steps indicate how to allow user to enroll 2FA, however it does not include anything on how to check if 2FA is enabled from security rules.
In my application, you can write to certain documents in firestore only if you have 2FA enabled, how would I check that in security rules?

Comment: You can create custom-claim attributes and roles for that specific documents and give access to that specific role (2FA enabled users). https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#custom-claim_attributes_and_roles